# Problema em respeitar grids, adicionando campos dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

Bom dia,

Estou criando um formulário que o usuário irá adicionar mais campos dinamicamente ([Código referência](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/a-little-trick-for-grouping-fields-in-an-html-form/)), Porém o campo é criado mas não respeita as grids (Bootstrap4) que deveria seguir.

Exemplo:

[image: Problema]

Área selecionada em vermelho foi criada manualmente no código, está correto!
Porém a área Azul que foi criada dinamicamente deveria ocupar o mesmo tamanho que a área vermelha (manual) o que não ocorre :(

*OBS: Área vermelha e azul apenas são para exemplificar o local/tamanho.*

Segue o código ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsds96/f11n65zv/)), para visualizar o problema é necessário expandir ao máximo há área que renderiza o código.

Desculpe o código ruim, ainda estou estudando...

Agradeço desde já.

Atenciosamente,

Jeferson Silva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples amigo, dando uma olhada no link que você disponibilizou eu observei que você fazia um:

```
let container = document.getElementById('people-container');
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = template;
container.appendChild(div);
```

A ideia está correta, oque está errado é o lugar onde a `div people-container` se encontra. você está adicionando `form-row` dentro de um `form-row`, a solução para seu problema é colocar a div com id `people-container` fora da div `form-row`. Vou compartilhar o código com sua estrutura editado.

```
<body> 

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12" id="form">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
              <h1>Nome_Projeto</h1>
              <p><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, velit.</em></p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="NomeDE">Nome Data Exntesion:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NomeDE" placeholder="Nome Data Extension..." name="NomeDE" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="ExternalKey">External Key:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ExternalKey" placeholder="External Key..." name="ExternalKey" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row" >
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="NomeCampo">Nome Campo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NomeCampo" placeholder="Nome Campo..." name="NomeCampo[1]">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="TipoCampo">Tipo:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="TipoCampo" name="TipoCampo[1]">
                  <option>Text</option>
                  <option>Number</option>
                  <option>Date</option>
                  <option>Boolean</option>
                  <option>EmailAddress</option>
                  <option>Phone</option>
                  <option>Decimal</option>
                  <option>Locale</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="StatusCampo">Status:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="StatusCampo" name="StatusCampo[1]">
                  <option>Primary Key</option>
                  <option>Nullable</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="people-container"></div> // coloquei a div aqui, fora da div form-row
        <br><br>


        <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-center">
          <a href="javascript:;" id="add-new-person" class="add-new-person">+ Campo</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script  src="js/add.js"></script>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Bons estudos Jeferson. Confira o código funcionando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/f11n65zv/2/).

Comment: Cara muito obrigado ontem eu fiquei tentando várias coisas e não tinha chegado nisso!

Comment: Que ótimo que consegui te ajudar Jeferson, poderia marcar minha resposta como a certa ? É só você clicar no ícone de certo do lado da minha resposta :) .

Comment: já marquei irmão! Obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

1 - remove a div id="people-container", id deve ser unico, se necessario cria uma class

2 - usa o append de html em vez de criar div, essa nova div não vai conter estilos, e por isso não respeita as grids

```
let i = 2;
document.getElementById('add-new-person').onclick = function () {
    let template = `
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="NomeCampo">Nome Campo:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NomeCampo" placeholder="Nome Campo..." name="NomeCampo[1]">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="TipoCampo">Tipo:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="TipoCampo" name="TipoCampo[1]">
            <option>Text</option>
            <option>Number</option>
            <option>Date</option>
            <option>Boolean</option>
            <option>EmailAddress</option>
            <option>Phone</option>
            <option>Decimal</option>
            <option>Locale</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="StatusCampo">Status:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="StatusCampo" name="StatusCampo[1]">
            <option>Primary Key</option>
            <option>Nullable</option>
      </select>
    </div>

`;

let container = document.getElementById('people-container');
container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);

i++;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado também por responder!! de coração!